# How can I load rgee in R

Tags: google-earth-engine, rgee

I am trying to load rgee in R and getting this error message: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgee’:  .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgee', details:   call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)   error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ee'

tried to restart R but still getting the same error message